# llvm-2.8 dswp core dump linux

Tags: llvm

I new in llvm. I just compile google code and got this error.

```
Stack dump:

0.  Program arguments: opt -load /home/vahid/mywork/llvm-2.8/Release/lib/DSWP.so -dswp obj.o -o out.o 
1.  Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module 'obj.o'.
2.  Running pass 'Loop Pass Manager' on function '@fun'
3.  Running pass '15745 Decoupled Software Pipeline' on basic block '<badref>'
./execute: line 15:  2196 Aborted                 (core dumped) 
 opt -load /home/vahid/mywork/llvm-2.8/Release/lib/DSWP.so -dswp obj.o -o out.o
```

for more information you can see this link: http://code.google.com/p/15745-project-dswp/source/browse/

I used llvm-2.8, clang-2.8, fedora 15

Comment: i got this error  *** glibc detected *** opt: free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x09519300 ***